# Uniqueness of NSConstantString objects

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

> The simplest way to create a string object in source code is to use the Objective-C @"..." construct:
>
> ```
> NSString *temp = @"/tmp/scratch";
> ```
>
> Note that, when creating a string constant in this fashion, you should use UTF-8 characters. Such an object is created at compile time and exists throughout your program’s execution. The compiler makes such object constants unique on a per-module basis, and they’re never deallocated, though you can retain and release them as you do any other object. You can also send messages directly to a string constant as you do any other string:
>
> ```
> BOOL same = [@"comparison" isEqualToString:myString];
> ```

this is the Quote from [Creating Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-SW1) in ObjC documentation.

I've tested different @"" string in the applicationA ,also the libB that applicationA used.
All the @"", which are initialized using string=@"..." mode and having the same content are all pointing to same memory address.

Thus, I don't understand the meaning of the "per-module basis", what does "per-module" mean? lib based? app based? file based?

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of Mac OS X and iOS development, a module is equivalent to a single .m/.mm/.c/.cpp file.